# How to override react-skylight min-height in next.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

These days I am developing the next.js project. I am using react-skylight to create a modal. I want to override `min-height`. In skylight already had skylight-dialog CSS class. I have already attached the image regarding CSS and prop.

```
const myBigGreenDialog = {
     backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
     color: '#000',
     width: '50%',
     height: '200px',
     padding: '3rem'
   };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React skylight in 2018-04-03 v0.5.1 Change dialog style height to minHeight. try like this prop.

```
const myBigGreenDialog = {
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  color: '#000',
  width: '50%',
  minHeight: '250px',
  padding: '3rem'
};
```